# Cannot fix screen resolution

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, display-resolution

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed on a hp ProBook 650. The screen resolution is too small.

(here is a screenshot)[image]

I can't figure out how to reconfigure the graphics settings.

Here is the output from `$ lspci -knn | grep -A2 VGA`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0416] (rev 06)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1993]
Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Comment: I see no problems on the screenshot

Comment: @Pilot6: it's very small.. I want something like http://www.google.fr/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fi1-news.softpedia-static.com%2Fimages%2Fnews2%2FUbuntu-13-04-Screenshot-Tour-Preview-2.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Flinux.softpedia.com%2Fblog%2FUbuntu-13-04-Screenshot-Tour-Preview-347124.shtml&h=768&w=1366&tbnid=lnIqja8wnTGP_M%3A&docid=LxtjYMUrNXa9JM&ei=YzL9VbDDFYT4aqTSi9AF&tbm=isch&client=ubuntu&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=1599&page=1&start=0&ndsp=20&ved=0CD8QrQMwCmoVChMI8IDy0OuCyAIVBLwaCh0k6QJa

Comment: What do you mean "small"? Resolution can be high or low. You can change resolution in System Settings -> Screen. But if you set it not to native resolution for the LCD screen, quality may be bad. You can change icons size instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `xrandr` - a useful guide on setting up a resolution can be found [here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-change-display-resolution-settings-using-xrandr.html).

Unfortunately, a lot of people have trouble making the commands permanent, so that they run on startup, but I'll show you how to do it the easy way:

- Create a bash script, `xrandr.sh` for example, and place your xrandr commands into it. It should look something like this

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  xrandr --newmode "1920x1200_60.00"  193.16  1920 2048 2256 2592  1200 1201 1204 1242  -HSync +Vsync
  xrandr --addmode VGA1 1920x1200_60.00
  xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1920x1200_60.00
  ```
- Make the script executable with `chmod +x xrandr.sh`
- Search for "Startup Applications" in the dash, run it, and add the script as a startup application.

The commands will now run every time you log into your account.

**OR** you can go the easy way and use a program that does the above for you -  [ResolutionX.](https://sourceforge.net/projects/resolutionx)